# Selenium Facebook security check's captcha not visible

Tags: java, selenium, security, recaptcha, geckodriver

[image]

I am using Firefox driver and I am doing some tests on the Facebook pages. In several times, I get captcha but I am using a captchaSolver API to fix that. For now, captcha is completely invisible and I don't know why. Also there is nothing in the captcha's frame, it is empty. Is this happening because of the Facebook's security issues or is there any problem with my driver. Because I can easily see the captcha with browsers (Chrome,Firefox...)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/base/geckodriver.exe");

                FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                profile.setPreference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 0);
                profile.setPreference("dom.popup_maximum", 0);
                profile.setPreference("privacy.popups.showBrowserMessage", false);
                profile.setPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
                profile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
                profile.setPreference("dom.push.enabled", false);
                profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US");

                FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                options.addArguments("--lang=en-us");
                options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.FATAL);

                if (bHeadless) {
                    options.addArguments("--width=1920", "--height=1080");
                    options.setHeadless(true);
                }

                options.setProfile(profile);
                wDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

                wDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                wDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line

```
options.addArguments("-private");
```

Essentially running it incognito by using the method addArguments and adding the arg       –private to the code.

Comment: I will try this at work. You know this is not suitable for now because of the IP issues. But I wonder that why did you think that -private notation is useful for my situation?

Comment: It looks more of a rendering issue , since running incognito provides a clean browser context I think it might just work out for you.

Comment: Kind of related...https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10207076582608629

Comment: I saw it before but I don't know mann. Thanks anyway, I will try to find a solution